# dismiss popover in ios on didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uipopovercontroller

I am having one popover which pop up on navigationbar button and that pop up contains a tableview.
How can dismiss popover in ios on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method of tableview?

Comment: Can you show the code where you have popover the Popup?

Comment: @NDoc http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/display-popovers-on-the-ipad check this for code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meant that a tableView is inside that popover and your popover controller is instantiated like this:

**Objective-C**

In the containing controller, place this on the top of it:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIPopoverController *popOver;

//this is the content of the popover
MyTableVC *tableVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myTableView"];
//this is the navigation controller of your tableViewController
UINavigationController *popNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableVC];
//this is you popover
self.popOver =[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popNav];
```

then you have to dismiss it inside that viewController, which you have created the popover from, in this case it's popNav for example.

So in you MyTableVC class you need to call this method in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: pedrouan
ioscreator.com/tutorials/display-popovers-on-the-ipad  im using somthing like this

Comment: I know @rva and my solution fits to it. Don't forget to apply property (nonatomic,strong) UIPopoverController *popOver;

Answer (score 1):

You can use

**Obj-c**

```
[popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

**Swift**

```
popoverController.dismissPopoverAnimated(true)
```